# Yii radioButton with different models

Tags: yii, radio-button, radiobuttonlist

So I have this code ... well this is just a sample

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'First_Session'); ?>
    <?php echo $form>radioButton($model,'first_session',array('c'=>'')/**array('size'=>45,'maxlength'=>45)*/); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'first_session'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'Second_Session'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->radioButton($model,'second_session',array('c'=>'Checked')/**array('size'=>45,'maxlength'=>45)*/); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'second_session'); ?>
</div>
```

So my question is how to apply the radiobutton here .... see, i have two fields, the first and second session but what i need to do is when first session is marked the second session couldn't be. I am still new to yii.

Comment: Is the input valid if neither `first_session` nor `second_session` is checked?

Comment: that code is just an example :D but yeah

Answer (score 0):

Use [`CHtml::radioButtonList()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#activeRadioButtonList-detail) instead of `radioButton()`. You can declare an extra variable `$session_val` in your model and use this to set the value of the selected 'session' before validation.

Model

```
class Model1{
   ....
   public $session_val;
   ....
   public function beforeValidate(){
       unset($this->first_session);
       unset($this->second_session); //unset first_session and second_session
       if(isset($this->session_val))
           $this->$session_val=true; //set first_session or second_session
       else
           $this->addError(...);
       return parent::beforeValidate();
   }

   public function rules(){
       return array(
           ...
           array('session_val','safe'),
           ...
       );
   }
```

view

```
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'session_val'); ?>

<?php echo $form->radioButtonList($model,'session_val',array('first_session'=>'First Session','second_session'=>'Second Session'));?>
```

Comment: I have two fields in the same model, when i want to check the first session the second session shouldn't be or can't be checked because the first one is already checked, my problem is i can't figure out how to do it